# Parsec separator / terminator

Tags: haskell, parsec

Apparently I'm too dumb to figure this out...

Consider the following string:

```
foobar(123, 456, 789)
```

I'm trying to work out how to parse this. In particular,

```
call = do
  cs <- many1 letter
  char '('
  as <- many argument
  return (cs, as)

argument = manyTill anyChar (char ',' <|> char ')')
```

This works perfectly, until I add stuff to the end of the input string, at which point it tries to parse that stuff as the next argument, and gets upset when it doesn't end with a comma or bracket.

Fundamentally, the trouble is that a comma is a *separator*, while a bracket is a *terminator*. Parsec doesn't appear to provide a combinator for that.

Just to make things more interesting, the input string can also be

```
foobar(123, 456, ...
```

which indicates that the message is incomplete. There appears to be *no way* of parsing a sequence with two possible terminators and knowing *which one* was found. (I actually want to know whether the argument list was complete or incomplete.)

Can anyone figure out how I climb out of this?

Comment: `arguement = many1 (noneOf ",()")`

Comment: Whoops, didn't read correctly. There is a combinator for that - `sepBy` and `sepBy1`. So `arguement \`sepBy\` (char ',')`

Comment: Should it really be `foobar(123, 456, ...` or `foobar (123, 456, ...)`?

Comment: @kosmikus It really is what I wrote. (I.e., no close bracket if the list is incomplete.) That's what makes it so fiddly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should exclude your separator/terminator characters from the allowed characters for a function argument. Also, you can use `between` and `sepBy` to make the difference between separators and terminators clearer:

```
call = do
  cs <- many1 letter
  as <- between (char '(') (char ')')
      $ sepBy (many1 (noneOf ",)")) (char ',')
  return (cs, as)
```

However, this is probably still not what you want, because it doesn't handle whitespace properly. You should look at `Text.Parsec.Token` for a more robust way to do this.

#### Edit

With the `...`-addition, it indeed becomes a bit weird, and I don't think it nicely fits into any
of the predefined combinators, so we'll have to just do it ourselves.

Let's define a type for our results:

```
data Args = String :. Args | Nil | Dots
  deriving Show

infixr 5 :.
```

That's like a list, but it has two different kinds of "empty list" to distinguish the `...` case. Of course, you can also use `([String], Bool)` as a result type, but I'll leave that as an exercise. The following assumes we have

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>), (<$), (*>))
```

The parsers become:

```
call = do
  cs <- many1 letter
  char '('
  as <- args
  return (cs, as)

args = do
      (:.) <$> arg <*> argcont
  <|> Dots <$ string "..."

arg = many1 (noneOf ".,)")

argcont =
      Nil <$ char ')'
  <|> char ',' *> args
```

This handles everything fine except whitespace, for which my original recommendation to look at token parsers remains.

Let's test:

```
GHCi> parseTest call "foobar(foo,bar,baz)"
("foobar","foo" :. ("bar" :. ("baz" :. Nil)))
GHCi> parseTest call "foobar(1,2,..."
("foobar","1" :. ("2" :. Dots))
GHCi> parseTest ((,) <$> call <*> call) "foo(1)bar(2,...)"
(("foo","1" :. Nil),("bar","2" :. Dots))
```

Comment: Changing the argument parsing to `sepBy (many1 (noneof ",)")) (char ',')` allows me to handle the final terminator manually, and basically allows me to do everything I want. (I'm unconcerned about whitespace; this is only for snipping log text apart.)